# how to do simple addtion using argv function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to do simple addtion using `argv` in `python`.

Here is my code:

```
import sys

x = int(sys.argv[1])
y = int(sys.argv[2])
z = x + y

print(z)
```

I am running this program in `python 3.4`, but it is throwing `IndexError`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The IndexError means you didn't pass any command line arguments. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments

Answer (score 2):

How are you trying to run your script?
I ran "python3.6 sample.py 1 2" on my linux machine. That worked for me. 
Index error will be thrown out if you don't give enough arguments while you are trying to execute the code. As you mentioned sys.argv[2]. You must give atleast 2 arguments after the filename to run this code.

For example, if you run the code like "python3.6 sample.py 1" Index error will be thrown out.

Comment: when i am running this in command prompt ,it is working. But when i am running in IDLE python shell it is throwing that Index error.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that your script did not get enough parameters that you are trying to access.

Try printing `sys.argv` to see what actually gets passed in.

Or you could build a more robust code:

```
import sys

def calc():
    print('argv:', sys.argv)

    try:
        x = int(sys.argv[1])
    except IndexError:
        print('no value for "x"')
        return
    except ValueError:
        print('value for "x" is not an integer')
        return

    try:
        y = int(sys.argv[2])
    except IndexError:
        print('no value for "y"')
        return
    except ValueError:
        print('value for "y" is not an integer')
        return

    z = x + y
    print('z: ', z)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    calc()
```